# I'm trying to re-create a Caesar Cipher by reading said text from a file and encrypting by 2 keywords

Tags: python-3.4

Basically, my program when run just comes up with this error 'output2.append(chr(BASE + (ord(letter)- BASE + newKey2[pos]) % 26))
IndexError: list index out of range'
Here is my code:

```
BASE = ord('A')
choice = input("Would you like to encrypt?")
key = input("Please enter a keyword to encrypt by: ").upper()
key2 = input("Please enter a keyword to encrypt by: ").upper()
#keyword to upper case
key = [ord(letter)- BASE + 1 for letter in key]
key2 = [ord(letter)- BASE + 1 for letter in key2]
count = 0 #This sets the count to 0
file = open("Test.txt","r")
while True:
    MSG = ''.join(chr for chr in file)
    if not chr in file: break 
newKey = (key*len(MSG))[:len(MSG)]

newKey2 = (key2*len(MSG))[:len(MSG)]     
output = []
output2 = []
pos = 0 

for letter in MSG:
    output.append(chr(BASE + (ord(letter)- BASE + newKey[pos]) % 26))
    pos += 1
print(output)

for letter in output:
    output2.append(chr(BASE + (ord(letter)- BASE + newKey2[pos]) % 26))
    pos += 1
print(output2)
print("Your encrypted message is:", ''.join(output2))        
file.close()
```

Comment: Weclome to Stack Overflow.   As a first step, you should create an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.    You'll probably find the issue while you do it.  If you don't, you'll end up with a question more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pos` doesn't automatically reset to 0, which is why you are getting the error. After the loop `for letter in MSG:`, your `pos` variable is `len(MSG)`. You are then trying to access that index in your next loop, and you are still incrementing `pos`. What I mean is you aren't accessing `newkwy2[0], newkey2[1], newkey2[2], ...` but `newkwy2[len(MSG)], newkey2[len(MSG) + 1], newkey2[len(MSG) + 2], ...`

To avoid this error, you can either reset the variable to zero between the loops or try something like this:

```
for index, letter in enumerate(output):
    output2.append(chr(BASE + (ord(letter)- BASE + newKey2[index]) % 26))
```

This way you don't even need to use your `pos` variable.